# osm tile server renderd command not found

Tags: openstreetmap, ubuntu-14.04

using [this](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/) set of instructions to make an OSM tile server (on Ubuntu 14.04).

When I run this `sudo -u my_username renderd -f -c /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf` the terminal reports `renderd: command not found`.

Any ideas why this would be? I have everything in the instructions up to this point working and i dont see a note on how exactly to install renderd, its just part of `mod_tile`. I thought about trying to get around the issues by running the `renderd.py` file and supplying the file path to my `renderd.conf` file, but i get more issues as the OSMBright.xml file contains fonts `mapnik` can't find, despite setting all the font dirs correctly...maybe more on this issues later.

For now I'd be grateful if anyone can shed light on why my install cant find the command `renderd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. The instructions are missing a line after doing the `make` step for `mod_tile`, there should be a `make renderd` command too. That way the binary for renderd is actually generated and will respond

Answer (score 0):

try to find correct path to renderd. like /usr/local/bin/renderd

Comment: I would expect */usr/local/bin/* to be contained in Ubuntu's `$PATH` but searching for the `renderd` binary is nevertheless a good idea.

Comment: Hi. So, that file path doesn't exist on my machine. Dies that suggest renderd isn't installed? What would the binary file look like? I can find renderd.init in ~/src/mod_tile/debian