# osm tile server optimisation

Tags: geospatial, ubuntu-14.04, openstreetmap, postgresql-9.3

I'm aware of multiple blog posts, wiki's and other posts in the community on the subject of **optimising an OSM tile server** as described [here](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/). As of those instructions, and some additional tweaks (like my [`make renderd`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27237303/osm-tile-server-renderd-command-not-found) question), I have a working tile server.

**My question:** can the community suggest precise ways to increase the performance of tile rendering.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 on a VM with 20 CPUs and 65GB of RAM, so lots to play with. Having read documentation and adjusted the `postgresql.conf` file and added extra indexes as suggested [here](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/issues/207), I don't really get what I'm looking for i.e. a simple `Leaflet.js` based page looking at my server often shows a grey tile after about a minute of waiting.

I can see PostgreSQL (9.3) responding to requests and doing `SELECT` queries using `htop`. Often the CPU is **not** anywhere near 100%, neither is the memory usage. I have also run an `ANALYZE` on the database as suggested in the GitHub issue linked to above.

Comment: What about disk throughput? Check your IO wait. Ideally your whole database should be on a reasonably fast SSD. Also note that low zoom levels will usually take way longer to render than high zoom tiles, therefore they are often pre-rendered. Also see [similar questions at help.openstreetmap.org](https://www.google.de/#q=site:help.openstreetmap.org+tile-server+performance).

Comment: Thanks. I'll check the io and update my question ASAP. The last part of your response brings me to ask "how do install render_list"? I have a render_list.c file but I can't call it/use it in the terminal.